# PHP/MySQL - Checking for double meeting room booking

Tags: php, sql

I want to find rows for anytime during the new period I'm requesting.

Here is my table data which has existing rows:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1s4y8tl6s09emim/Screenshot%202014-04-04%2009.52.24.png
```

Here is the new period I'm requesting:

```
Date: 2014-04-03 
Start Time: 12:30:00
End Time: 13:30:00
```

What is the correct `SQL` to find any existing rows for anytime during the new period I'm requesting?

I have this so far but not sure about the `start_time` and `end_time` fields.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM int_low_events WHERE start_date = "2014-04-03"';
```

Comment: Are the columns `start_date` and `end_date` defined as DATETIME?

Comment: Table structure: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qe6f8p040l8gan7/Screenshot%202014-04-04%2010.40.39.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *, 
       ADDTIME(start_date, start_time) AS start,
       ADDTIME(end_date, end_time) AS end,
       '2014-04-03 14:00:00' AS proposed_start,
       '2014-04-03 16:05:00' AS proposed_end
  FROM int_low_events
HAVING (start BETWEEN proposed_start AND proposed_end OR end BETWEEN proposed_start AND proposed_end)
    OR (proposed_start BETWEEN start AND end OR proposed_end BETWEEN start AND end)
```

This is exactly the same as my previous (working) answer, but it is (in my opinion) a lot easier to understand. Also you now don't have to fill in the proposed start- and end-dates everywhere, but instead only once (`... AS proposed_start` and `... AS proposed_end`).

This does work according to [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ae93d/23) with your database design.

---

It needs to be so complicated, as it needs to fetch any event, that's running at the time of the new *proposed* event.

```
id | start_date | start_time | end_date   | end_time
---+------------+------------+------------+-----------
62 | 2014-04-03 | 12:00:00   | 2014-04-05 | 13:00:00
63 | 2014-04-03 | NULL       | 2014-04-04 | NULL
64 | 2014-04-03 | 16:00:00   | 2014-04-03 | 17:00:00
65 | 2014-04-03 | 16:30:00   | 2014-04-03 | 17:30:00
66 | 2014-04-03 | 21:30:00   | 2014-04-03 | 22:30:00
```

This is the part of your database that matters. Assume we have a new event, that has the following dates: `2014-04-03 16:00  -  2014-04-03 18:00`. With my previous query, it only selected the IDs 64 and 65 (as both of these have either the start_datetime OR end_datetime within our new event).

However ID 62 does also span over this timeframe, but starts earlier AND ends later. With the new query, this will also be selected (if this makes any sense to you).

Comment: Hmmm. I've setup my table in SQL Fiddle so it matches my setup only laptop. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ae93d/1

Comment: Row count: 0 for my SQL query when there should be 1 row overlapping.

Comment: No rows found as the events im testing against is booked over multiple days. Is it possible to add in multiple day checks?

Comment: When the events go multiple days, it's going to be a little more difficult. I'll assemble something for this.

Comment: Messy stuff going on there now, I'm going to enhance it when I'm back from lunch break, but at least it's working already.

Comment: OK I found a problem. If I try booking an event for 2014-04-03 between 09:30 and 12:00, I have overlapping events. But the overlapping event doesnt start until 12, where as my new event finishes at 12.

Comment: cartbeforehorse - I CANNOT CHANGE THE TABLE STRUCTURE.

Comment: @cartbeforehorse Therefore I have updated my query so that it works with multiple days. - I will create an updated version of my query that looks easier to understand and isn't as messy as now.

Comment: @SeanDelaney I get that.  But you did just accept an answer which doesn't work.  You have to find a way of combining date and time, else your SQL will be impossibly complex.

Comment: The query I provided in this answer __does__ work with multiple days, thus it combines date and time (using `ADDTIME()`).

Comment: @Padarom did you see my comment where I found an issue?

Comment: @Padarom It may do, after you modified it. :-)  My comment was on your original, unmodified answer.  Besides, even with your modified answer, I think your SQL is more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: @SeanDelaney I have reformatted the code and changed it a little bit. Also there's a description in my answer, stating why it needs to be so complicated. I hope this is finally what you wanted! ;)

Comment: @Padarom Simpler logic would be to say `WHERE proposed_start < confirmed_end and proposed_end > confirmd_start`

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you have I field `date` in your table:

```
 $sql = 'SELECT * FROM int_low_events WHERE date between '2014-04-03 12:30:00' and '2014-04-03 13:30:00'";
```

Comment: I cannot change the table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea to check if two events are overlapping : you could use `BETWEEN` like this :

```
SELECT a.event_id, b.event_id 
FROM int_low_events AS a, int_low_events AS b
WHERE b.site_id = a.site_id AND
b.start_date = a.start_date AND
b.start_time BETWEEN a.start_time and a.end_time
```

This will work for events during less than one day, as the ones in your database screenshot.

You may need to adapt it for events during more than one day.

Comment: I need to check for overlapping events before I add a new event based on the new events date, start time and end time.

Comment: So new event details are: 2014-04-03, start time of 12:30:00
end time of 13:30:00.  I need to find overlapping rows

Answer (score 0):

So despite this being billed as a PHP question, it's actually a database question?? ;-)

Hopefully your date-time combination are already encoded in the table as a date-time field, and not as two separate date and time fields.  If this is not the case, then I strongly suggest that you build a view which combines these two fields into one.  Drastically simplifies your SQL, and your maintenance costs (for anyone trying to modify in the future).

**If you don't do this, then you will have serious problems when searching on events which span several days, as is evident in other answers on this page.**

Also, you need to change your incoming request to a date-time combination.  You can do this in your PHP code before binding to the SQL variable.

The SQL then looks like this...

```
select *
from   int_low_events a
where  :proposed_start_datetime not between a.start_datetime and a.end_datetime
  and  :proposed_end_datetime not between a.start_datetime and a.end_datetime
```

-- edit --
Depending on which database you have underlying all this, there are different ways to combine the date and time fields.  Use `ADDTIME()` if you're using MySQL.  Other databases will have their own ways of doing the same thing, thus allowing you to build the solution into your SQL rather than having to modify the database logic.

Comment: Telling me to use ADDTIME when I have very little SQL knowledge is not going to help me. I'm copying and pasting SQL queries into a PHP string and running it...

Comment: First of all I'm not a student. Second of all I didn't ask you to do my job. I've come on here to seek help in an area where my knowledge is weak in - MySQL. If I were to try and do this myself I'd get nowhere fast and probably give up! I'm not a "know it all" like you. At least with the answers Padarom provided, I can take the solution apart and learn from it. Thanks of your help!

Comment: And for those of you who want to know why I can't change the DB structure is because I'm using a third party PHP plugin for the CMS I'm using but I need to extend the PHP to do extra checks before making a new event booking.